# How can I share a object(field) made in a superclass to all it subclasses without having to instantiate again?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

The problem that I am facing is that I want to reduce the number of calls made to make the object as that call is very taxing. So instead of calling the service many times to get the object in each of the subclasses I intend to have the same object be shared in all the subclasses. I understand that making the field static can make the same object be shared among all the copies of a instance of classes. But needs to be done in the above mentioned case.

Comment: Can you explain your logic on code example? Is that field is primitive type or object?If it is object I think I have an idea if I didn't get you wrong.

Comment: I have found a workaround. What I did is where I am calling all the subclasses there I have passed the instance to all of them.